# How to get cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

Creating cookie

```
session_start();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();    
setcookie(session_name('USERNAME'),'HAMZA',1,
      isset($params['path']),
      isset($params['domain']),
      isset($params['secure']),
      isset($params['httponly']));

session_regenerate_id(true);
echo "COOKIE IS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY !";
```

Now fetching cookie value

```
session_start();
$NAME=$_COOKIE['USERNAME'];
echo $_COOKIE["USERNAME"];

if(isset($NAME))
{
      if($NAME=='USERNAME')
      {
          echo "success";
      }
      else
     {
          echo "error";       
     }    
 }
```

Please Help Me !

Result

Why they create Auto random Value Like: u8omuum6c9pkngrg4843b3q9m3).
But i want to get my Original COOKIE value Which is "HAMZA" ?????

Comment: have you heard about `$_COOKIE` superglobe variable

Comment: use `print_r($_COOKIE);` or `var_dump($_COOKIE);`

Comment: i now but return answer like this 
echo $NAME=$_COOKIE['HAMZA']; 
631mfeuu1k50v8s7327dpm5gd4error

Comment: It's straing that you `setcookie(session_name(.....` line not giving you a fatel error. Please check

Comment: `isset($paenter code hererams['httponly'])` here you are going to get fatle error.

Comment: Can you please tell your expected outcome, by putting it in your code. thanks.

Comment: This IS my CODE:


<?php

  session_start();

 $params = session_get_cookie_params();

 setcookie(session_name('USERNAME'),'HAMZA',1,isset( $params['path']),isset( $params['domain']), isset($params['secure']),isset($params['httponly']));

 session_regenerate_id(true);

 //echo "SUCCESS";

 $NAME=$_COOKIE['USERNAME'];
 

 echo strtok($_COOKIE["USERNAME"],"|");

  if(isset($NAME))
  {
   if($NAME=='HAMZA')
   {
    echo "success";
    
    
   }
   else
   {
    
    echo "error";
    
   }
   
  }
 // foreach ($NAME as $key=>$val)
 //{
 // echo $key.' is '.$val."<br>\n";
  //}
  ?>

Answer (score 41):

This is the PHP syntax for cookie creation:

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
```

The first variable is your cookie name, which you can use to read the value like this:

```
$_COOKIE['YOUR COOKIE NAME'];
```

**Note:** Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script. This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including `<html>` and any whitespace.
Also note that dots and spaces (`.`/ ) in cookie names are replaced with underscores (`_`).

**Documentation:** [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), [`$_COOKIE[]`](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.cookies)

Comment: I try but giving answer like this:
cb3rsosrc0cetg42od84ol9jd6error

Comment: Can you please tell your expected outcome, by putting it in your code. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Function session_name will give you hash which atucally is you session identifier.
It seems like you want to get USERNAME stored in session, don't you? In that case you should use $_SESSION array.

#### Code example:

```php
setcookie($_SESSION['USERNAME'],'HAMZA',1,
      isset($params['path']),
      isset($params['domain']),
      isset($params['secure']),
      isset($params['httponly']));
```

And you can get it like this:

```
$myCookie = $_COOKIE[$_SESSION['USERNAME']];
```

But from your second code it's not quite clear what you want to get.
If you want to ask for $_COOKIE['USERNAME'] and get 'HAMZA' then you should set it like this:

```
setcookie('USERNAME','HAMZA',1,
      isset($params['path']),
      isset($params['domain']),
      isset($params['secure']),
      isset($params['httponly']));
```

And when you retrieve it $NAME=='USERNAME' makes no sense, because it will be like $NAME=='HAMZA':

```
$NAME=$_COOKIE['USERNAME'];
echo $_COOKIE['USERNAME'];

if(isset($NAME))
{
      if($NAME=='HAMZA')
      {
          echo "success";
      }
      else
     {
          echo "error";       
     }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one ...

`setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, 1800, "/");`

change expires time with:

`setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+ 1800, "/");`

and get

`$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];`

Comment: The question asks how to _get_ a cookie.

Answer (score -2):

try this one ...

```
<?
   $yummy = json_decode(json_encode($_COOKIE));

   if(isset($yummy->yourvar)) echo $yummy->yourvar;
?>
```

Why using encode and decode ?, it use to convert type Array to JSON
originally type $_COOKIE is Array

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should one encode and decode that cookie array?

Comment: hehehe thanks.

Why using encode and decode ?, it use to convert type Array to JSON
originally type $_COOKIE is Array

Comment: And why is JSON needed here? Why not access that cookie array directly?

Comment: actually depending on the style of the programmer, there are those who like the array and there are those who like json.
and I like JSON :)

Comment: If you like JSON, why are you using stdClass in the given example?